# Null character breaks pipe in find -exec

Tags: pipe

I'm trying to find every Perl script under a given directory, and run a script I wrote on them. I came up with something like

```
find . -type f -exec file {} \; | grep perl | awk -F':' '{print $1}' | myscript
```

I'm concerned about there beiong a ':' in a filename somewhere, so though I'd use `file`'s `--print0` option to give me something like

```
find . -type f -exec file --print0 {} \; | grep perl | awk -F'\0' '{print $1}' | myscript
```

It doesn't work. I get a bunch of `` find: `file' terminated by signal 13 `` errors instead, which I understand to be indicating a broken pipe. Is there either:

a better way to grab the path to all of my Perl scripts, or

a way to avoid the null character from breaking the pipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really simple, after all:

```
find . -type f -exec file --print0 "{}" + | \
perl -aF'\0' -lne 'print$F[0] if/perl/i'
```